# Renaming table of content to something else

Tags: table-of-contents

Please how do I rename my table of content title from "content" to "table of content"?
I am using a report class please

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc might be related?

Comment: I don't think so... mine is a thesis. Please help.

Comment: This answer can probably help, even though its question is marked as a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499069

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if the following example helps.

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Content}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]